# I need help getting nfts out of a stake pool account and back into the account owners wallets

Tags: authority, stake, bpf, upgrade-authority

We had a dev create a stake pool and host on his domain.

Domain now ded, and all nfts locked in pool

I have access to the authority wallet that created the pool and bpf upgradeable loader
https://solscan.io/tx/5tsLtz92n5vC8MeQcP5kMnpVbxSZxesprupatQp5A23FQ6Yf6SGErGGC7wYKGZrzGW789CwexRMprZr4qtqRyxrz

Can anyone help walk me thru how to release nfts in this pool back to the owners using the authority wallet?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information here. For example, what program / protocol are you using to store the NFTs?